# Parse ISIN out of String

Tags: regex, r, statistics

I want to parse an ISIN out of a really weird String, my code looks like that:

```
> df <- fread("C:/Users/WZHPCH/Desktop/Error Messages/df.csv", sep=";", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
> dput(df)
structure(list(ID = c(1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 24L), VAL = c("TES+XS0255015603+ae2s", 
"TEST*XS0255015603+d2aasd", "safd*adf*XS0255015603++", "gasdfs*dsa*US0917971006", 
"asdfsUS0917971006adf", "sd-asd-afds-US0917971006")), .Names = c("ID", 
"VAL"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000000110788>)
> df$parsedISIN <- gsub("^[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{10}$", '\\1', df$VAL)
```

What am I doing wrong with gsub?

Any recommendation?

I appreciate your reply!

Comment: what is df.gem ? In df, how do you identify practically an ISIN?

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel I change my code. However, now it sems tha my regex does not work... Any recommendation?

Comment: Looks better now :) i added the answer with `gsub`

Comment: As I said below, unless you're _absolutely_ sure you're going to be extracting fully valid ISINs with that regex, you should at _least_ use the regex with prefix validation *and* you really do need to look at the check digit validation.

Comment: FYI, an ISIN is 2 characters (a country code) followed by 10 **alphanumeric** characters (in uppercase). And as @hrbrmstr stated, the final character is for validation checking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few problems here:

1) Even though the question used `dput` the object has a pointer in it so it won't be usable on other systems.  I have edited out the pointer to give:

```
df <-
structure(list(ID = c(1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 24L), VAL = c("TES+XS0255015603+ae2s", 
"TEST*XS0255015603+d2aasd", "safd*adf*XS0255015603++", "gasdfs*dsa*US0917971006", 
"asdfsUS0917971006adf", "sd-asd-afds-US0917971006")), .Names = c("ID", 
"VAL"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

2) The code refers to `df.gem$Attributes`.  It should be `df$VAL`.

3) The `gsub` should be `sub` because there is only one occurrence in each component.

4) The match only matches if it starts at the beginning of the string and ends at the end of the string but will not match if its within the string which is the case here.

5) To use sub we need to match everything and just capture what we need so that we can exclude what we do not need.

Try this:

```
pat <- ".*([a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{10}).*"
sub(pat, "\\1", df$VAL)
```

which gives:

```
[1] "XS0255015603" "XS0255015603" "XS0255015603" "US0917971006" "US0917971006"
[6] "US0917971006"
```

Here is a visualization of the regular expression, `pat` :

```
.*([a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{10}).*
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/OKs_yGb63tqe8iOF)

**Note:** A slightly easier approach is to use a `strapplyc` in [gsubfn](http://gsubfn.googlecode.com) which directly extracts the pattern.  In that case the regular expression simplifies slightly:

```
library(gsubfn)
strapplyc(df$VAL, "[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{10}", simplify = TRUE)
```

Here is a visualization:

```
[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{10}
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/Nf0nRTs_3oMIyxe1)

Comment: Be warned that this is not a valid RegEx pattern for an ISIN code. An [ISIN code is a 12-character alpha-numerical code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Securities_Identification_Number), so that means that "letters" can appear any where in the last ten positions of the string and not only "numbers" (e.g. GB00B8Y82097).

Answer (score 4):

You can extract just the ISIN with `str_extract` and a good ISIN regex:

```
library(stringr)

VAL <- c("TES+XS0255015603+ae2s", 
         "TEST*XS0255015603+d2aasd", "safd*adf*XS0255015603++", "gasdfs*dsa*US0917971006", 
         "asdfsUS0917971006adf", "steve", "sd-asd-afds-US0917971006")

isin_pat <- "(BE|BM|FR|BG|VE|DK|HR|DE|JP|HU|HK|JO|BR|XS|FI|GR|IS|RU|LB|PT|NO|TW|UA|TR|LK|LV|LU|TH|NL|PK|PH|RO|EG|PL|AA|CH|CN|CL|EE|CA|IR|IT|ZA|CZ|CY|AR|AU|AT|IN|CS|CR|IE|ID|ES|PE|TN|PA|SG|IL|US|MX|SK|KR|SI|KW|MY|MO|SE|GB|GG|KY|JE|VG|NG|SA|MU)([0-9A-Z]{9})([0-9])"

str_extract(VAL, pat)

## [1] "XS0255015603" "XS0255015603" "XS0255015603" "US0917971006"
## [5] "US0917971006" NA             "US0917971006"
```

(I added the `"steve"` in there just to show what it returns when it doesn't find anything).

ISIN codes also need/should undergo validation (i.e. check digit) unless you're absolutely sure you'll be getting valid ones from the extraction.

To assign it to a data frame column:

```
df <- str_extract(VAL, pat)
```

Comment: Wow thx! How could this be added as a column to the dataframe?

Comment: Wow did write this `isin_pat` vector by hand ?!

Comment: @DavidArenburg it's a standard ISIN prefix validation ISIN. Found it in my Dash snippets library from ages ago. I've had to wrangle my fair share of diverse data in the past. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Basically, if you proceed with replacement in `gsub`, you need to put parenthesis on the group you want to isolate:

```
> df
   ID                      VAL
1:  1    TES+XS0255015603+ae2s
2:  2 TEST*XS0255015603+d2aasd
3:  4  safd*adf*XS0255015603++
4:  2  gasdfs*dsa*US0917971006
5:  3     asdfsUS0917971006adf
6: 24 sd-asd-afds-US0917971006

> df[,isin:=gsub(".*([A-Z]{2}[0-9]+).*","\\1",VAL)]
> df
   ID                      VAL         isin
1:  1    TES+XS0255015603+ae2s XS0255015603
2:  2 TEST*XS0255015603+d2aasd XS0255015603
3:  4  safd*adf*XS0255015603++ XS0255015603
4:  2  gasdfs*dsa*US0917971006 US0917971006
5:  3     asdfsUS0917971006adf US0917971006
6: 24 sd-asd-afds-US0917971006 US0917971006
```